# Const wrapper for iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, template-meta-programming

***Edit**: added clarification for why I want this, and updated the code since I don't have any answers yet*

I have a C++11 array-like class which (can be) a wrapper around a random-access iterator.  Index-based access and `.begin()`/`.end()` can just pass through to the iterator, but there's a bit of complication when the object is `const`:

```
    template<class Size, typename DataIterator>
    class Storage : public Size {
        DataIterator iterator;
    public:
        Storage(const DataIterator &iterator, const Size &size) : Size(size), iterator(iterator) {}
        
        auto operator[](index_t i)
                -> decltype(iterator[i]) {
            return iterator[i];
        }
        auto operator[](index_t i) const
                -> MakeConst<decltype(iterator[i])> {
            return iterator[i];
        }
        
        DataIterator begin() {return iterator;}
        ConstWrapper<DataIterator> begin() const {return iterator;}
        DataIterator end() {return iterator + this->size();}
        ConstWrapper<DataIterator> end() const {return iterator + this->size();}
    };
```

If we simply returned `DataIterator` from the `const` version of `.begin()` and `.end()`, then people holding a `Storage const &` would (incorrectly!) be able to modify the array through that iterator.

Containers like `std::vector` have two separate iterators (`::iterator` and `::const_iterator`), but our `Storage` class only has the read-write one, so we synthesise one using `ConstWrapper`:

```
    template <typename Iterator>
    class ConstWrapper {
        Iterator iterator;

        using traits = std::iterator_traits<Iterator>;
    public:
        using difference_type = typename traits::difference_type;
        using value_type = typename traits::value_type;
        using pointer = ConstWrapper;
        using reference = MakeConst<typename traits::reference>;
        using iterator_category = typename traits::iterator_category;
    
        ConstWrapper() {}
        ConstWrapper(const Iterator &iterator) : iterator(iterator) {}
        
        // The problematic cases:
        auto operator[](index_t i) const
                -> MakeConst<decltype(iterator[i])> {
            return iterator[i];
        }
        auto operator*() const
                -> MakeConst<decltype(*iterator)> {
            return *iterator;
        }

        bool operator!= (const ConstWrapper& other) const {
            return iterator != other.iterator;
        }
        /** All the other random-access iterator methods **/
    };
    
    // Specialisation to prevent infinite loops
    template <typename Iterator>
    class ConstWrapper<ConstWrapper<Iterator>> : ConstWrapper<Iterator> {
    public:
        using ConstWrapper<Iterator>::ConstWrapper;
    };
```

The implementation forwards all the relevant methods, and has a specialisation for `ConstWrapper<ConstWrapper<...>>` so that it can't wrap itself.

A key part is `MakeConst`, which turns types into the correct `const` variant (unlike simply adding `const`, which has no effect on references):

```
    // Converts (T & -> T const &), and (T -> const T)
    using MakeConst = typename std::conditional<
        std::is_reference<T>::value,
        typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const &,
        const T
    >::type;
```

Does this make sense, and is it OK?  Is there something else I could be doing which is more readable/efficient/etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: [edit] your question to add your whole project here

Comment: @Aryan Sorry, I don't understand what's missing.  (I didn't think the implementation of the `Size` classes were relevant.)

Comment: Why make a wrapper around an iterator? It doesn't make any sense. Just use the iterator itself.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want to do (and why). It would be nice to have an example of usage for const and non-const versions. If you have C++20, then perhaps you can just use `std::span` instead ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span ).

Comment: @ALX23z - if you iterate over a mutable container, the iterator returns mutable references when dereferenced (e.g. `int &`).  If you iterate over a `const` container, you *should* get an iterator which produces const references (e.g. `const int &`) or actual values (`int`).  `std::vector` does this, producing separate `iterator` and `const_iterator` types (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin).

Comment: Ok, I see what you wanted. ConstWrapper will not work for fundamental reasons as it requires an iterator to instantiate it. A mutable non-const iterator. While if your class is a const it won't be able to supply a non-const iterator unless you use a const cast which you shouldn't do. Also the const and non-iterators might be very different types with very different behaviours - say if accessing the class requires to make a locking operation. For const version one could just do a shared_lock while mutable requires unique_lock You shouldn't just assume it is a trivial wrap.

Comment: @ALX23z Our Storage class gets instantiated with a mutable non-const iterator, so we already have that. A const Storage still contains the same (mutable non-const) iterator, so could just return that - but then the user would have an iterator which can modify the data. So we want a different iterator, and it seems it should be possible to construct one.

Comment: @ALX23z To illustrate: a `std::vector<bool>::const_iterator` returns `bool` values (not references) when accessed.  A `std::vector<bool>::iterator` returns some other object (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) - but it's not copyable, and all the methods that would actually *change* the data are non-const.  So, `const Storage<Size, std::vector<bool>::iterator` would produce `ConstWrapper<std::vector<bool>::iterator>` for iteration, which _could_ return a `const std::vector<bool>::reference` which (because it's const) still doesn't allow modification of the data.

Comment: That was the other issue, that a Storage class is instantiated from iterator and contains one... it doesn't make sense. I'd expect Storage class to store and manage data. Instead it is a reference to a completely different container. Are you aware that iterators tend to get invalidated all the time?

Comment: @ALX23z Yeah - the larger project has Storage classes which manage their own data (and the iterator situation is also much simpler there).  This is one specialisation of Storage, used as a temporary wrapper for other containers.  I omitted that because it's `ConstWrapper` which I was mostly hoping to get feedback on.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your specialization is doing what you think it's doing. https://godbolt.org/z/Gfh7sv

You don't want `ConstWrapper<ConstWrapper<Iterator>>` to *inherit from* `ConstWrapper<Iterator>`; that would mean that a `CW<CW<I>>` "is-a-kind-of" `CW<I>`, which isn't true. You don't want an inheritance relationship here. What you want is simply for specializations of `Storage` to *not wrap* `DataIterator`s that happen to be specializations of `ConstWrapper` already. The way you do that is with an extra layer of alias indirection:

```
template<class T> struct maybe_constwrap { using type = ConstWrapper<T>; };
template<class U> struct maybe_constwrap<ConstWrapper<U>> { using type = ConstWrapper<U>; };

template<class Size, typename DataIterator>
class Storage : public Size {
public:
    using iterator = DataIterator;
    using const_iterator = typename maybe_constwrap<DataIterator>::type;
    ~~~
};
```

Now, if `DataIterator` is already a `ConstWrapper`, then both `iterator` and `const_iterator` will be literally the same type... which is what you want.

---

Your `MakeConst` seems to be predicated on the dubious idea that `const _Bit_reference` is not going to be assignable-to. That's likely to change in C++23. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63412623/should-c20-stdrangessort-not-need-to-support-stdvectorbool for some context.

---

You repeat some metaprogramming in the return types of `operator*` and `operator[]`. They should just return the type `reference` which you have already computed above.

```
reference operator*() const { return *it_; }
```

Incidentally, I'm changing your data member's name from `iterator` to `it_`, because I suspect it is a terrible idea, Concepts-wise, to have a container-ish class type with a member named `iterator` which member is (A) not public, and (B) not a type.

---

Your `operator!=` should probably use the hidden friend idiom:

```
friend bool operator==(ConstWrapper a, ConstWrapper b) { return a.it_ == b.it_; }
friend bool operator!=(ConstWrapper a, ConstWrapper b) { return a.it_ != b.it_; }
```

In C++20 you could theoretically omit `operator!=` and provide `operator==` only. I don't know yet if that's a good idea.

Passing `ConstWrapper` by value should be fine, because it holds only an iterator, and iterators are cheap to copy.

Comment: Thanks, this is really great

Comment: For the `MakeConst` point: now you point it out, yeah the constness of pointers/references is divorced from the constness of the values, so the fact that it worked for `std::vector<bool>::reference` in C++11 was itself not correct. So... am I going to need a whole shim-const-reference class, or does it mean `MakeConst` just isn't possible?